# How to resolve abstract static method design issue?

Tags: java, abstract-class

I have several queues that all extend a `Queue` class. I want to do a Queue manger base class to handle adding to the queue (and other operations).

If you take a look at the following code, I created a base class called `QueueManger` that has a static method called `add()` that will get 'Queue' and add a variable to it. I want to make `getQueue()` (called in add() ) abstract because I want to force other classes to provide their own implementation of the 'Queue'. The issue is I can't declare abstract static method. What is the right way to solve this?

```
public class RegistrationQueueManger {
    @Override
    Queue getQueue() {
        return new RegistrationQueue(); // RegistrationQueue is a class that
                                        // extends Queue.java
    }
}

public abstract class QueueManger {
    abstract static Queue getQueue(); // Error: cant do! (in java)

    public static Add(String myvar) {
        getQueue().add(myvar);
    }
}
```

*Note: I saw some question about this subject but it didn't really give a good answer of how to solve it and create another design to handling it.*

Comment: Read answers below, and use singleton pattern instead of your code

Comment: If he wants to extend the QueueManager, it should not be static or a singleton.

Comment: Right, what about making RegistrationQueueManger a singleton? is that right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only instance methods may be overridden. So abstract on a static method doesn't make sense. The `getQueue` method shouldn't be static, and the `add` method shouldn't be static either.

Answer (score 1):

That's because abstract method has to be overridden (implemented) and static method is not inherited. Anything that's static belongs to the class itself where it's declared. So, if you if you make `getQueue()` static it will be a class method that will belong to the class `QueueManger` class itself. So, make it an instance method, so that every class that extends the `QueueManger` will have their own `getQueue()`.

Answer (score 0):

refer to Android `Parcelable` interface design:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.0.1_r1/core/java/android/os/Parcelable.java