# Design Pattern to Avoid Abstract Static Methods (or Overriding a Static Method)

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, static-methods, abstract

I know that static methods can't be [abstracted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838808/how-to-resolve-abstract-static-method-design-issue) nor can they be overridden, [only hidden (and in which case late bindings don't happen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831426/is-it-possible-to-override-a-static-method-in-derived-class). With regard to this, I am struggling with a logical way to express the following relationship:

```
public abstract class Spell {
    protected int power;

    public Spell(int power) {
        this.power = power;
    }

    public int getPower() { return power; }

    // I know this is impossible, but please bare with me
    public abstract static int getMaxPower();
}

public class AttackSpell extends Spell {
    public AttackSpell(int power) {
        super(power);
    }

    public static int getMaxPower() { return 50; }
}

public class HealSpell extends Spell {
    public HealSpell(int power) {
        super(power);
    }

    public static int getMaxPower() { return 30; }
}
```

In this contrived example, max power is an attribute that I expect every spell to know (and every subclass of `Spell` has an individual max power that applies to all instances of itself). In other SO threads, the proposed solution to this impossible situation is to make `getMaxPower()` an instance method. However, I don't think this makes sense because power is an implementation detail that is useful to know before instantiation (eg. Constructing an array of spell instances from power 1 to the max power of that spell).

A solution that I see is creating a factory for each spell (or a more generic one for all spells), which has an instance method `getMaxPower()` that knows the max power attribute of the spell which it instantiates. However, this also doesn't seem optimal to me because:

1. It makes more sense for each spell to know its own properties
2. This makes the subclass of Spell oblivious to an implementation detail (namely, its constructor can't check whether a provided power exceeds its max power)

Is the factory pattern the correct approach? If so, what would be the logical justification to it? If not, is there a pattern that more appropriately fits this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disconnect generating spells from spell would be my first thought.

Have a class that described a spell family with a power range and then use that to create a collection of spells in the range, passing power etc through the constructor.

You could then think about some sort of data file save you a lot of hard coding.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can only override non-static functions, I see only one way doing this: You have to attach the information to the `Class` object somehow.

But this is no design pattern, i know...

You best annotate your class with the information and use reflection. Since annotations can be inherited, this should be exactly the behaviour you want. See `main` in Spell for an example how to use it.

Definition of the annotation type:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Inherited
public @interface SpellInfo {
    int maxPower();
}
```

NOTE: `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is the value for "undefined" here.

```
@SpellInfo(maxPower = Integer.MIN_VALUE)
public class Spell {
    protected int power;

    public Spell(int power) {
        this.power = power;
    }

    public int getPower() { return power; }

    public static int getMaxPower(Class<? extends Spell> c) {
        return c.getAnnotation(SpellInfo.class).maxPower();
    }

    public final int getMaxPower() {
        return getMaxPower(this.getClass());
    }

    // test it
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Spell.getMaxPower(Spell.class)="+
                                   Spell.getMaxPower(Spell.class));
        System.out.println("Spell.getMaxPower(AbstractSpellType.class)="+
                                   Spell.getMaxPower(AbstractSpellType.class));
        System.out.println("Spell.getMaxPower(HealingSpell.class)="+
                                   Spell.getMaxPower(HealingSpell.class));
        System.out.println("Spell.getMaxPower(AttackSpell.class)="+
                                   Spell.getMaxPower(AttackSpell.class));
        Spell spell = new AttackSpell(3);
        System.out.println("((Spell) new AttackSpell(3)).getMaxPower()=" +
                                   spell.getMaxPower());
        spell = new HealingSpell(4);
        System.out.println("((Spell) new HealingSpell(4)).getMaxPower()=" +
                                   spell.getMaxPower());

    }
}
```

AbstractSpellType inherits the annotation from Spell

```
public abstract class AbstractSpellType extends Spell {

    public AbstractSpellType(int power) {
        super(power);
    }

}



@SpellInfo(maxPower = 30)
public class HealingSpell extends Spell {

    public HealingSpell(int power) {
        super(power);
    }

}



@SpellInfo(maxPower = 50)
public class AttackSpell extends Spell {
    public AttackSpell(int power) {
        super(power);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Are annotations like these considered a best practice?

Answer (score 0):

A simple method is to make `getMaxPower()` into a factory method. Behind the scenes it instantiates an instance of itself, caches it and queries the instance.